# Following Python Lazy Logging Formatting, but pylint is still showing (logging-not-lazy) messages

Tags: python, unix, logging, formatting, pylint

I'm logging some info messages and wanted to make sure I was following the PEP standards. Pylint says that this line:

```
        LOG.info('Directories have been made in /home/bushbak2/projects/'+
                 'system_file_audit/%s/', manu)
```

Is not following the lazy logging format of python.
Could it be because the line carries over?

This is the message I get from pylint:

```
auto_audit.py:157:8: W1201: Use lazy % formatting in logging functions (logging-not-lazy)
```

Why does pylint still raise this message? Am I not appropriately following the PEP standard?

Cheers,
Brendan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `+` in your expression. Pylint sees it as a string concatenation and thus, recommends you to do this concatenation lazily.

You can fix it by removing the `+`:

```py
LOG.info('Directories have been made in /home/bushbak2/projects/'
                 'system_file_audit/%s/', manu)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the `+` between the two strings is that adds an add operation that must be evaluated in runtime before calling LOG.debug.

This can be a performance problem if you have to evaluate this line too often even if the debug logging flag is not set for your program.

This is the abstract syntax tree for `logging.debug("this is " + "a test %s", 123)`:

[image: logging.debug("this is " + "a test %s", 123)]

As you can see, the first argument of the function call *always* has an add operation.

On the other hand, if we use `logging.debug("this is " "a test %s", 123)` (with whitespace instead of a `+` sign). The python compiler produces this other AST:

[image: logging.debug("this is " "a test %s", 123)]

What happens with f-strings? A lot of people (including me) is in love with python f-strings. If we pass an f-string, the result is similar to the one with the plus sign.

The AST for `logging.debug("this is a test {123}")` shows python must perform a string operation before the function call:
[image: logging.debug("this is a test {123}]